# mailx MTA problem in ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: mail

This command line works but there isn't attachment (but works all fine in ubuntu 10.04)

```
echo "body of your email" | mailx -a "foo.zip" -s "TEST" foo@foo.com
```

because?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have come across *one* of the differences between the package `bsd-mailx` and the package `heirloom-mailx`. Undoubtedly you are using the `bsd-mailx` package (the default for Ubuntu) which does *not* have the `-a` option to attach files.

The easiest solution is to install the `heirloom-mailx` package, ensuring first that the `bsd-mailx` package is removed, and then your command line will function as you intended...